# comment out lines in /fstab with bash script

Tags: bash

I need a bash script command to look in /etc/fstab and find the line that contains a mount name "/mymount"  and just puts a "#" at the beginning of the line to comment it out.

from this:

```
    /dev/lv_mymount /mymount  ext4    defaults        1 2
```

to this (with a #):

```
    #/dev/lv_mymount /mymount  ext4    defaults        1 2
```

Comment: Can you not just Vi it?

Comment: Sadly no ... I need to make a function that does this in a repeatable way ..

Comment: `sed -i '\@/mymount@s@^@#@' /etc/fstab` (you might not need the leading '\' char by the first `@`.) Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I think you gave me the right command, respond so I can accept it.

Comment: looks like @john1024 has a better explanation and only posted later becuase he was writing it up. I'd recommend accepting that. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Using sed:

```
sed -i '/[/]mymount/ s/^/#/' /etc/fstab
```

How it works:

- `-i`

  Edit the file in-place
- `/[/]mymount/`

  Select only lines that contain `/mymount`

  - `s/^/#/`

  For those selected lines, place at the beginning of the line, `^`, the character `#`.

#### Using awk:

```
awk '/[/]mymount/{$0="#"$0} 1' /etc/fstab >/etc/fstab.tmp && mv /etc/fstab.tmp /etc/fstab
```

How it works:

- `/[/]mymount/ {$0="#"$0}`

  For those lines containing `/mymount` and place a `#` at the beginning of the line.
- `1`

  This is awk's cryptic shorthand for "print each line."

Comment: thank you!  surprisingly that isn't really out on the web, I would find this of a lot of value to people.